# How to correctly reset vertex attributes after modification

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

I am trying to use the same vertex shader for two different use cases to preserve memory, but I am having issues where the modifications of one shader run are passed on to the next run, even after being reset. Specifically, I am trying to use the shader to both show a regular texture, while also modifying the vertex attributes in some cases to show portions of a texture. The problem is, this "cropping" of the texture is applied to the texture that should be shown 100%.

Here is what it looks like, where the sprite on the right is drawn first:
[image: Application screenshot]

Both textures are showing only a portion of their actual images, but only the one on the left should be doing so. Strangely, the one on the right shows a full texture for a second, before being replaced with what is shown. This tells me that the vertex attributes of the first sprite are modified by the second (left) sprite, but I don't know how to reset them. Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

Here is how I modify the vertex attributes:

```cpp
void setSelection(Quad selection) {
        vertices[3] = selection.x + selection.w;
        vertices[4] = selection.y + selection.h;
        vertices[8] = selection.x + selection.w;
        vertices[9] = selection.y;
        vertices[13] = selection.x;
        vertices[14] = selection.y;
        vertices[18] = selection.x;
        vertices[19] = selection.y + selection.h;
};
...
float vertices[20] = {
          // positions         // texture coords
          0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
          0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
         -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
         -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
};
```

This code changes the shown vertex array's texture coordinates. They are applied with this code:

```cpp
void Sprite::render() {
    // Set shader uniforms if the shader is initialized
    if (shader != nullptr) {
        applyTransforms();
        shader->useShader();
        shader->setMat4("transform", trans);
        shader->setVec4("color", color.asVec4());
        shader->setMat4("view", Camera::getLookMat());
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    tex->bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```

However, if I have two objects (both instances of the same class), one with a modified array (left) and one with an unmodified array (right, as shown in the picture), the modified array takes precedence, and I can't figure out how to keep it from being changed without using a different shader object, but I don't want to do that. Is there anything I am missing that would allow me to change the attributes in between draw cycles?

**ADDITION 1**
Here is the entire `Sprite` class (right image is an object):

```cpp
Sprite::Sprite(std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader) : tex(texture), color(1u, 1u, 1u, 1u), shader(shader) {
    glInit();
}

Sprite::Sprite(const std::string& path, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader) : tex(new Texture(path)), color(1u, 1u, 1u, 1u), shader(shader) {
    glInit();
}

Sprite::~Sprite() {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    vao = NULL;
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    vbo = NULL;
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    ebo = NULL;
}

void Sprite::setColor(RGBA color) {
    this->color = color;
}

void Sprite::render() {
    // Set shader uniforms if the shader is initialized
    if (shader != nullptr) {
        applyTransforms();
        shader->useShader();
        shader->setMat4("transform", trans);
        shader->setVec4("color", color.asVec4());
        shader->setMat4("view", Camera::getLookMat());
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    tex->bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

void Sprite::glInit() {
    // GL initialization
    // Buffers
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies), indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Verticies
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * FLOAT_SIZE, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * FLOAT_SIZE, (void*)(3 * FLOAT_SIZE));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

Here's the header:

```cpp
class Sprite : public Object{
public:
    Sprite(std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader = nullptr);

    Sprite(const std::string& path, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader = nullptr);

    ~Sprite();

    void setColor(RGBA color);

    inline RGBA getColor() const { return color; };

    virtual void render();

    inline std::weak_ptr<Texture> getTexture() const { return tex; };

protected:
    // Pointers for texture and shader (if initialized)
    std::shared_ptr<Texture> tex;
    std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader;

    GLuint vbo = 0, vao = 0, ebo = 0;

    RGBA color;

    float vertices[20] = {
          // positions         // texture coords
          0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
          0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
         -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
         -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left
    };

    GLuint indicies[6] = {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    // Initialize GL objects
    virtual void glInit();
};
```

And here's the subclass (left image, header only):

```cpp
class SpriteSheet : public Sprite {
public:
    SpriteSheet(std::shared_ptr<Texture> texture, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader = nullptr) : Sprite(texture, shader) {};

    SpriteSheet(const std::string& path, std::shared_ptr<Shader> shader = nullptr) : Sprite(path, shader) {};

    ~SpriteSheet() { Sprite::~Sprite(); };

    void setSelection(Quad selection) {
        vertices[3] = selection.x + selection.w;
        vertices[4] = selection.y + selection.h;
        vertices[8] = selection.x + selection.w;
        vertices[9] = selection.y;
        vertices[13] = selection.x;
        vertices[14] = selection.y;
        vertices[18] = selection.x;
        vertices[19] = selection.y + selection.h;
    };
};
```

The `Object` class only contains positional vectors, and is therefore not relevant. `RGBA` and `Quad` are abstractions of `glm::vec4`.

**EDIT 2**
I have figured out that if two `SpriteSheet` objects are declared, the one declared last will be the one that takes priority with its texture coordinates being applied to all objects, regardless of render order.

Comment: "*I am trying to use the same vertex shader for two different use cases to preserve memory*"- even though you probably have an underlying problem (in code you've not yet shown us), are you aware that you're not even saving 1 kilobyte of memory here; this is a bad case of micro-optimization.

Comment: Just to confirm, `setSelection` is a class method and `vertices` are a member of the same class? So you are not modifying the same global array via a free function?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 `vertices` is actually a member of the `Sprite` class (same as the `render` method), whereas `setSelection` is actually a member of a subclass of `Sprite`. All functions shown are class functions.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus I understand where you are coming from, but another reason is that I don't want to have to iterate over every single object that has a copy of a shader object when I want to change a uniform. I will edit the question to show the whole class.

Comment: I may not have understood the whole magnitude. A uniform is uniform during a draw call. To use a single draw call for multiple objects i'd assemble the buffer(s) so that it contains the vertices and indices in the order i need them. Have you considered primitive restart, or instancing and writing per object information for example into a texture or a different buffer for look up via the instance id ? Or use multiple draw calls for the time being.

Comment: @a_donda Well at the time being, I am using two different render calls to draw the two sprites shown on screen, which I am OK with. What I'm talking about is using a single *shader*, but with different texture coordinates and uniforms assigned for each draw cycle. **The uniforms change correctly, the vertex data doesn't.** That's my problem. I see what you mean by ordering verts and indices, but eventually I am going to have so many objects on screen that won't be practical. About writing object info into a texture, I don't fully understand and I don't know if that will work long-term.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that before modifying vertex attributes (VBOs), I had to rebind the VAO of the created object. The modified render code looks like this:

```cpp
void Sprite::render() {
    // Set shader uniforms if the shader is initialized
    if (shader != nullptr) {
        applyTransforms();
        shader->useShader();
        shader->setMat4("transform", trans);
        shader->setVec4("color", color.asVec4());
    }
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    // ^ This is very important

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    tex->bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
```